# How to put a state in automaton in the middle in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, automata

I'm drawing an automaton consisting of three states. Where the second state is on the right of the first state, and I want the third state to be below first and second, but right in the middle, meaning to have same distance to both first and second state. Currently, I have something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5 cm, scale=1, transform shape]

    \node[initial,state,accepting,initial text=] (AG) {$AG$};                                    
    \node[state]    (BH)    [right of=AG]             {$BH$};
    \node[state]    (EA)    [below right of=AG]       {$EA$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This draws the third state closer to the second state, and as I said I want it to be right between the first two states. Also, I have `H` option for the figure, but the automaton is not centered. If I include a caption, the cation is centered, but the automaton is not. Any idea how to center the automaton too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read some of the very nice and useful Tutorials in pgfmanual. Probably you already consulted the second one "A Petri-Net for Hagen", but you could also read the fourth "Diagrams as Simple Graphs" where `positioning` library is introduced (more details in section 17.5.3 `Advanced Placement Options`). With `positioning` library you can declare something like `below right= a and b of c` where `a` and `b` are distance to `below` and `right` respect of node `c`. So in this particular you can say:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm, scale=1, transform shape]

    \node[initial,state,accepting,initial text=] (AG) {$AG$};                                    
    \node[state]    (BH)    [right=of AG]             {$BH$};
    \node[state]    (EA)    [below right= 1.5 and 1.5 of AG]       {$EA$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A nice automaton}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]

Note: `\centering` command inside `figure` centers `tikzpicture`.